# netplan as a firewall

Tags: firewall, netplan

Will netplan add firewall features? I just started using firehol and something with similar syntax in yaml with the same pattern of `netplan apply` would be great.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Ubuntu already has the UFW firewall, and you can install `gufw` as a firewall GUI.

Comment: The way firehol configures the firewall is much different that ufw. The problem with it development has come to a standstill and it uses a custom format to configure the firewall. It would be great there was an alternative to ufw that's configuration is in yaml and works like netplan or is part of netplan.